# Python3 threading, using double function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I want to get which output like this;

```
[+] Trying <here number>
Hello 1000
Hello 1001
Hello 1002
.
.
.
8
Hello 1009
.
.
.
Hello 9999
```

But for me, output is just this;

```
[+] Trying 1000
[+] Trying 1001
[+] Trying 1002
[+] Trying 1003
[+] Trying 1004
[+] Trying 1005
.
.
.

[+] Trying 9999
```

Code

```
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def t(payload):
    print("Hello " + str(payload))
    
p = 0

def times(a):
    p += 1
    
    if p%8 == 0:    
        print("8") 

    t(a) 
         
 
for i in range(1000, 10000, 1):
    ThreadPoolExecutor(50).submit(times, i)
               
    sys.stdout.write('\r[+] Trying %s' % str(i))
```

Can you help me about what I'm doing false?

I think code should run like this:

1. Program should use 50 threads
2. In for loop, it should execute times function with i parameter
3. Times function should say 8 when i is divisible by 8

Comment: For a start, it would help if you wrote a newline at the end of your outputs, not at the start. Further, use the same output method, i.e. either `print()` or `sys.stdout`. This isn't necessarily the cause of corrupted output, bit makes things clearer. Lastly, each iteration, you create a new pool with up to 50 threads and run a single task in it, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: This is not original code, in original code i'm using it for send request and really it must be fast :)

Comment: I sure hope that code conform to a [mcve]. BTW: Please take the [tour] and read [ask], as a new user here!